# Does Amazon Redshift automatically clean up disk space used for temp tables and work tables created when a query spills to disk?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I recently started a new job that uses Redshift for the db platform. They have been struggling with disk space issues and noticed that when they restart the server they reclaim about 20% of used disk space. Disk space will then start to climb steadily until basically the whole disk is full and they have to reboot again.

In SQL Server (the only other db I have worked with), this behavior can happen when the tempdb (database file that contains temp tables and work tables from spill overs) expanded unexpectedly. This can can fill up the whole disk if you don't manage it properly since the tempdb doesn't automatically shrink even when the massive temp tables are dropped when the query completes. But when the server restarted tempdb would shrink to the size you set for it.

All this to ask, does Redshift do something similar and reserve disk space for temp tables when the workload contains a lot of large temp tables and disk spill overs(which we absolutely have) ? If so how could I check? If not, what else could explain the sudden reclamation of 20% disk space when the database is rebooted?

Comment: Hard to say specifically what's happening on your cluster but you generally see disk space being reclaimed when Redshift performs a VACUUM on a table - a big difference between Redshift and SQL Server is that a delete or update on a Redshift table results in "soft delete" of rows which are not actually removed, and so continue to take up disk space, until a VACUUM process permanently removes them. Originally this had to be run manually but these days there is an auto-vacuum feature. If I was to take a guess maybe the vacuum is only happening for some tables when the cluster is restarted?

Comment: @NathanGriffiths Thanks for the info. I will look into this. Does the soft delete happen even on a truncate?

Comment: No, TRUNCATE immediately removes rows and doesn't require a VACUUM https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRUNCATE.html

Comment: *If* auto-vaccum is enabled *and* there are no scheduled vacuum processes running *and* the Redshift instance is under continual heavy load, you might find that auto-vacuum is not able to keep up with the amount of un-vacuumed data in the tables because by design it pauses during heavy query load (see https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-redshift-automatic-vacuum/). When the cluster starts up there won't be any queries running so potentially the auto-vacuum is kicking in then.